# Show all posts under a same custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I have a custom field called `"geo_location"`.

And under that field, there are total 5 different values (1 to 5).

Now, there are total 50 posts that have one of the five values.

For example, post#1 has geo_location="1" and post#2 has geo_location="3" etc.

Is there a way to show all the posts under the same 'geo_location' value?

So for example, I want to show all the posts under the same geo_location="1".

how can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use WP_Query to create a database query using your custom meta-data.

This is done like this:

```php
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'geo_location',
    'meta_value' => '1'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then you can output the result using the loop in the usual way.